# Fatal error Call to a member function filter()

Tags: taxonomy

I am using wordPress version 4.4.2 + Jupiter 5.08 on Apache 2.2.22 (Debian)

The website seems to be fully operational, but in the Apache error log I got this message :

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function filter() on a non-object
>   in wp-includes/taxonomy.php on line 805

This is the concerned line:

```
// Sanitize term, according to the specified filter.
$_term->filter( $filter );
```

I made some test to fix it (*like trying to dump `$_term`*) without success.

Only skipping the instruction would stop the error, but i don't think that would be the good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some entries has been deleted in the table `wp_term_taxonomy` causing this trouble. Database has been rollback before thoose changes and now it works.